# Asymptotic behavior of convex functions at $+\infty$ w.r.t $x^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

**MOTIVATION**

I am investigating the behavior of monotonic functions defined in some neighborhood of $+\infty$ in terms of the limit
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p},\tag{1}\label{1}$$
for $p> 0$.

Since the function is monotonic, the limit \eqref{1} always exists (either finite or infinite) for $p=0$.

In general, depending on $p$ the limit may be $0$, $\ell \neq 0$ (when $f(x) \sim kx^p$ for some $k$), it may not exist, and finally be infinite.

If the limit is $+\infty$ for some $\overline p$, it is infinite for also for $p< \overline p$, and, conversely, if the limit is $0$ for $\overline p$, it is $0$ for any $p>\overline p$. In between, we might have an interval (or a singleton) of values of $p$ for which the limit is either finite and non null or nonexistent.

It is easy to construct examples where the limit is either $0$, $+\infty$, or nonexistent *for all $p>0$*.

**It is also possible to construct functions for which the limit is $+\infty$ for $p\leq \overline p$, and $0$ for $p> \overline p$.** Consider, for example, for $x\geq 1$,

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^{\frac{k+1}k} & \left(k^{k} \leq x < (k+1)^{k}\right)\\
(k+1)x & \left((k+1)^{k}\leq x < (k+1)^{k+1}\right)
\end{cases}, \ \ \ k=1,2,\dots
$$

See Figure below.

[image: 0enter image description here]

We have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^p} = +\infty$$
when $p\leq 1$, and
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^p} = 0,$$
for $p>1$.

---

**QUESTION**

I can only, think, however of *non convex functions* that have the above feature. Is this a limitation?

Thus we have:

> Does there exist a **convex function** $f(x)$ and a positive number $\overline p$ such that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p} = +\infty$$
> for $p\leq \overline p$ and and $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p} = 0$$ for $p>\overline p$?

Do you have  any hints on how to constuct it (if the answer is yes) or to prove that the answer is no (if that is the case)?

Comment: $x \ln x$ on $(1,\infty), \overline p=1$?

Comment: @geetha290krm, thanks.. Apparently I drowned in an inch of water...